# how to pass multiple integer parameter value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, type-conversion

I have a stored procedure that has structure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetUserFullName

(@NoteStoreType INT = NULL) 

AS
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.tblUsers.LastName + ', ' + dbo.tblUsers.FirstName as UnderwriterName
FROM            tblUsers
WHERE           tblUsers.Type =  COALESCE(@NoteStoreType, tblNoteStore.Type )
```

In my SSRS report I want to say if `@NoteStoreType= NULL` then select ALL NoteStoreTypes, if not then use `@NoteStoreType` that user will select.

If I allow multiple values then it gives me an error converting datatype int to string.

[image]

Can I do that in SSRS without changing anything in my stored procedure?

Comment: If you want to allow user to select multiple values in your parameter you will have to change your SP. Why don't you just use `where  tblUsers.Type IN (@NoteStoreType)` and set all values as default value in your parameter? Also note your parameter is not set to allow nulls so your SP won't take the parameter null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple parameters that are selected will get passed to stored proc as a string. You will need to change stored proc to split this string. Also if you want to pass null you will need to check the allow null value.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot `Allow null value` when you have `Allow multiple values` selected.

Comment: Clearly from the screenshot you can, maybe you can't now but this was a couple of years ago so maybe the product has changed- I don't know I've not used it for a long time.

Comment: True it may have changed since your answer.  I do know that for SQL 2014 (and I assume higher) if you select both values, it will complain about multiple values not allowing null.